# How to set collation details for a table in bigquery when creating table in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using the below python snippet to create table in a dataset in bigquery. However I am unable to find a way to set default collation to the table.

```
schema = client.schema_from_json(file_name)
table = bq.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table.time_partitioning = bq.TimePartitioning(
type_=bq.TimePartitioningType.MONTH,
field=partition_field, )
table = client.create_table(table)
```

can anyone help in setting up default collation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated this code from Google's official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_collate_statement) by using DDL statements in python, Called a query job to create a table.
Can you try this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
project = 'ProjectIdHere'
dataset_id = 'datasetIdhere'
table_id = 'tableIdHere'
client = bigquery.Client(project=project)

sql = """
CREATE TABLE datasetIdhere.tableIdHere
(
  x INT64 OPTIONS(description="An optional INTEGER field"),
  y STRUCT<
    a ARRAY<STRING> OPTIONS(description="A repeated STRING field"),
    b BOOL
  >
)
DEFAULT COLLATE 'und:ci' #Collate line here
PARTITION BY _PARTITIONDATE
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2025-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
  partition_expiration_days=1,
  description="a table that expires in 2025, with each partition living for 24 hours",
  labels=[("org_unit", "development")]
)

""".format(
    project, dataset_id, table_id
)

job = client.query(sql)  # API request.
job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish.

print(
    'Created new view "{}.{}.{}".'.format(
        job.destination.project,
        job.destination.dataset_id,
        job.destination.table_id,
    )
)
```

Query body is a sample from the documentation. I added the default collate line and got the result here:

[image]